# I am not able to delete image but insert in working fine with same directory using Flask

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-mysql

i am trying to remove image from a folder but it was not working giving a error : FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'static\images\2018194259_a476v_engelhart-tilburg_inside-track_text_font_product.jpg'

But insert is working very fine with same upload directory

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static\images'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

insert code :

```
def insert():
cursor = db.cursor()

if request.method == "POST":
    flash("Data Inserted Successfully")
    name = request.form['name']
    email = request.form['email']
    phone = request.form['phone']

    image = request.files['imgfile'] #myfile is name of input tag

    if image and allowed_file(image.filename):
        fileTemp = secure_filename(image.filename)
        time_p = time.strftime('%Y%H%M%S')

        filename = time_p+"_"+fileTemp

        image.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))

        path = filename
    empty=''
    if path is empty:
        return "You have not uploading a image"
    else:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO student_flask (name, email, phone)VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (name, path, phone))
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()

    return redirect(url_for('Index'))
```

Remove IMAGE Code:

```
@app.route('/delete/<string:id_data>', methods = ['GET'])
def delete(id_data):

   imgname = image_name(id_data)
   mna = imgname[0]
   os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], mna))
   return redirect(url_for('Index'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the DB to get the image's name first. If it's an object by itself .i.e. `Image.name` or an object attribute .i.e. `Foo.image`. In your delete function you must run [commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) for the changes to take effect. Also the `id` should be an `int`:

```
@app.route('/delete/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete(id=None):
```